# "Unballooning" RAM that's been ballooned by VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory, vmware-vsphere

Given the constrained RAM situation described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/528254/vsphere-education-what-are-the-downsides-of-configuring-virtual-machines-with), what is the cleanest method (manual or programmatically) to:

- Identify VMware virtual machines whose RAM has been reclaimed by the VMware balloon driver.
- *"Unballoon*" the RAM.

Assume that more physical RAM is available to the environment.

I've found that I can vMotion a VM to another host, and that clears the ballooned state. Is there any other method that works?

Note: I've added several hosts and ~512GB of RAM to the environment. The ballooned VMs did not trigger a DRS rebalance action or unballoon themselves. I've had to manually vMotion each of the affected virtual machines to clear this, as shown below...

---

*Here's the before...*
[image]

*And the after... Following a vMotion to another host in the cluster.*
[image]

Comment: If you identify the ballooned VMs programmatically, then you'd need to supply a destination to your script to move them to.  If this is a huge number of VMs/hosts, that may get complicated.  Would it be easier to just maintenance-mode each host, serially, until the whole cluster has been migrated?

Comment: That would make sense... if there weren't RAM constraints in the cluster :) But yes, this works as well.

Comment: I know this is an old article, but i found it whilst researching a similar issue, and here's some useful info I located - especially the bits relating to the unwinding of balloon driver allocations. According to research done by someone at Kingston.com...(see comments on http://frankdenneman.nl/2010/11/29/disable-ballooning/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VMware actually has a [KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003470) that has this information:

> To force the balloon driver to release its hold on memory and prevent
>   the guest operating system from using swap space, use one of these
>   options:
>
> - Set the value of sched.mem.max to the allocated memory or greater.
> - Select the virtual machine's Resources > Memory > Limit > Unlimited box.
> - Migrate the virtual machine to another host.

Comment: Unfortunate. I've added several hosts and a lot of RAM to the environment. The ballooned VMs did not trigger a DRS rebalance or unballoon themselves. I've had to manually vMotion each of the affected virtual machines to clear this state.