# Find all virtual machines with ballooned or swapped RAM in VMware cluster?

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

If I were to look at a vSphere cluster or resource pool and see a certain level of memory ballooning or swapping, how do I identify which VMs are affected? [I know what to do with them once I find them :)](https://serverfault.com/questions/528295/unballooning-ram-thats-been-ballooned-by-vmware)

In the example below, there are 65 virtual machines in the resource pool. There's just under 32 Gigabytes of ballooned RAM. How do I identify which VMs have a portion of their RAM ballooned or swapped?

[image]

Comment: If you want to simplify the code this is a one-liner:
Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | Where-Object {$_.Summary.QuickStats.BalloonedMemory -ne "0"} | select @{n='ComputerName';e={$_.name}},@{n='SwappedMemory';e={$_.Summary.quickstats.SwappedMemory}},@{n='BalloonedMemory';e={$_.Summary.quickstats.SwappedMemory}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powercli is great for things like this:

Get-VM | where {$_.BalloonedMemory -ne '0'}

Loads more examples are here:

http://www.getshifting.com/wiki/powerclinotes

Particularly have a look at "VMs with Ballooning and Swapping" 
http://www.getshifting.com/wiki/powerclinotes#resource_pools_with_ballooning_and_swapping

Copied from the above link:

```
$myCol = @()
foreach($vm in (Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | Where-Object `
  {$_.Summary.QuickStats.BalloonedMemory -ne "0"})){
    $Details = "" | Select-Object VM, `
    SwappedMemory ,BalloonedMemory

    $Details.VM = $vm.Name
    $Details.SwappedMemory = $vm.Summary.QuickStats.SwappedMemory
    $Details.BalloonedMemory = $vm.Summary.QuickStats.BalloonedMemory

    $myCol += $Details
  }
$myCol
```

Comment: You can paste code!

Comment: This worked, running in less than 2 minutes on a Virtual Center with ~1200 VMs. Question updated.

Answer (score 6):

Hope this will be a little bit of help.

Sorry, was quick so you would want to do additional sorts in this info output, as well as grouping by resources(host, datastore, cluster), I ran against the whole vCenter.

```
#!/bin/env python
__author__ = 'dladner'

import os
import sys
import pysphere

from pysphere import VIServer, MORTypes
from pysphere.resources import VimService_services as VI

s = VIServer()
s.connect("vcenter_hostname_or_ip", "username", "password")
vmlist = s.get_registered_vms(status="poweredOn")
count = 0
for vmpath in vmlist:
    pm1 = s.get_performance_manager()
    vm = s.get_vm_by_path(vmpath)
    mor = vm._mor
    ballooned = pm1.get_entity_statistic(mor, 77)
    swapped = pm1.get_entity_statistic(mor, 61)
    count += 1
    print "VM Number %d is %s and Ballooned Memory Amount on this VM is : %s" % (count, vmpath, ballooned)
    print "VM Number %d is %s and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : %s" % (count, vmpath, swapped)

print "NOTICE: This statistic refers to VMkernel swapping and not to guest OS swapping."
s.disconnect()
```

This will give you the result below where you can already modify and sort it the way you want from higher ballooned/swapped amount to lower (+ would want to convert KB to MB)

I did modified output (substituted hostnames and grouped by ballooned/swapped)

```
SWAPPED:

VM Number 2 is [vm11_rr] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-303427:swapped(61):Swapped::107336:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:35:33.561569>]
VM Number 9 is [vm04] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-17451:swapped(61):Swapped::7896:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:36:25.791696>]
VM Number 10 is [vm05_nq] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-266882:swapped(61):Swapped::816:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:36:33.266692>]
VM Number 11 is [vm06] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-4550:swapped(61):Swapped::-1:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:36:40.313133>]
VM Number 14 is [vm05] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-158642:swapped(61):Swapped::12532:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:37:02.907590>]
VM Number 23 is [vm07] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-437276:swapped(61):Swapped::135272:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:38:10.633787>]
VM Number 24 is [vm14_rr] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-74703:swapped(61):Swapped::183436:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:38:17.985025>]
VM Number 25 is [vm01] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-156212:swapped(61):Swapped::13268:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:38:25.224494>]
VM Number 33 is [vm14] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-156661:swapped(61):Swapped::828:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:39:25.827377>]
VM Number 39 is [vm23_rr] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-391487:swapped(61):Swapped::10020:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:40:10.795514>]
VM Number 48 is [vm15] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-446333:swapped(61):Swapped::-1:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:41:20.224237>]
VM Number 49 is [vm14_rr] hostname and Swapped Memory Amount on this VM is  : [<vm-395852:swapped(61):Swapped::91664:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:41:27.588455>]
vm number 51 is [vm03] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-47780:swapped(61):swapped::8:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:41:43.539276>]
vm number 54 is [vm29_rr] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-430048:swapped(61):swapped::1200:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:42:07.398927>]
vm number 56 is [vm03] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-45758:swapped(61):swapped::19560:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:42:22.790720>]
vm number 59 is [vm25_rr] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-267833:swapped(61):swapped::55836:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:42:46.202327>]
vm number 60 is [vm01] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-279859:swapped(61):swapped::4289160:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:42:53.200330>]
vm number 61 is [vm04] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-174860:swapped(61):swapped::26288:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:43:01.326958>]
vm number 62 is [vm25_rr] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-384185:swapped(61):swapped::8180:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:43:09.043827>]
vm number 63 is [vm12_rr] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-434605:swapped(61):swapped::25780:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:43:16.270494>]
vm number 64 is [vm01] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-372871:swapped(61):swapped::21840:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:43:23.820811>]
vm number 67 is [vm09_nq] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-184134:swapped(61):swapped::716:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:43:46.909753>]
vm number 69 is [vm31_rr] hostname and swapped memory amount on this vm is  : [<vm-434653:swapped(61):swapped::148:kilobytes:2013-08-31 04:44:02.652494>]

BALLOONED::
VM Number 23 is [vm07] hostname and Ballooned Memory Amount on this VM is : [<vm-437276:vmmemctl(77):Balloon::2638188:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:38:08.631993>]
VM Number 24 is [vm14_rr] hostname and Ballooned Memory Amount on this VM is : [<vm-74703:vmmemctl(77):Balloon::1335560:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:38:16.188130>]
VM Number 49 is [vm14_rr] hostname and Ballooned Memory Amount on this VM is : [<vm-395852:vmmemctl(77):Balloon::1249812:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:41:25.789048>]
VM Number 56 is [vm03] hostname and Ballooned Memory Amount on this VM is : [<vm-45758:vmmemctl(77):Balloon::-1:kiloBytes:2013-08-31 04:42:20.445191>]
```

If you need some additional help I can try to make it more sane tomorrow as today it is quite late.

SOURCES:

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/memory_counters.html

https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

P.S. Not sure what -1:kiloBytes means from API.

Comment: Thank you. Let me get connected and try this against the troubled environment.

Comment: I wonder if there's a quicker way to obtain this information.

Comment: yeah that one is slow.

Comment: I am positive there is a way to make it faster, that one is just a dorky prototype, i'll look into it.

Comment: @DanilaLadner, thanks for this answer. This script runs very slow. Is there a way to make this faster?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late addition to an old thread but you can make this faster keeping it in a pipeline and avoiding a for each loop. Give this a try:

```
    get-vm | where{ $_.swappedmemory -ne '0'} | get-view | Select Name,@{Name="Swapped”;Expression={$_.summary.quickstats.swappedmemory}},@{Name="Ballooned";Expression={$_.summary.quickstats.balloonedmemory}}
```