# vSphere | VMs are balooning and swapping | sched.mem.max paratmetar does not exist

Tags: performance, vmware-esxi, memory, swapping

I have two VMs in ESXi5.5 environment that are swapping memory. After a long research I found out the below two articles where it is explained that one must compare the values of `memsize` and `sched.mem.max` and they must be the same or `sched.mem.max` should be greater than `memsize`.

["Unballooning" RAM that's been ballooned by VMware](https://serverfault.com/questions/528295/unballooning-ram-thats-been-ballooned-by-vmware)

[VMWare KB1003470](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003470)

The problem is that I can not find this `sched.mem.max` parameter. I've checked the `.vmx` files on all of my VMs and at all of them that value missing.

We have a fairly large environment of multiple hosts and clusters. There is no VM with the `sched.mem.max` parameter. Also the VMs are all at version 10.

This is what I've done so far according to the KB article :

- Set the value of `sched.mem.max` to the allocated memory or greater. [DOES NOT EXIST]
- Select the virtual machine's Resources > Memory > Limit > Unlimitedbox.[CHECK]
- Migrate the virtual machine to another host. [CHECK] - and the other host started swapping too :(

Comment: If you can't find the parameter, you'll have to *set* it.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but where can I set that parameter? At `vm options` perhaps?

Comment: Open the *Edit Settings* dialog for the VM, go to the *VM Options* tab, srcroll down to, and expand, *Advanced*, then click on *Edit Configuration...*. Here you'll get a list of all the advanced config options and you can click *Add Row* to add the one you want. You'll need to shutdown the VM for this to work though, otherwise the *Edit Configuration...* button is greyed out.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this on one other Test VM (which didn't have swapping problems) just to see how the VM will behave afterwards. The two VMs who swap are critical production and can not be shut down right now. I will try this once I have a maintenance window and post the results than.