# VMware Machine CPU Configuration sweet spot (Server 2012 / 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, vmware-vsphere, central-processing-unit

Let's assume I had enough free ressources to allocate in my VMware vSphere 5.1 Landscape.

Can anyone point me to an optimal CPU Configuration (Number of virtual sockets / number of cores per socket) in regard of the sweet spot.

Where does allocating more sockets and cores not benefit the VM anymore?
Also, does this sweet spot vary between a Windows 2012 and a 2008 R2 Server?
Assume I am talking just about the OS performance, not the performance of any possible applications running on the server.

Thank you for your inputs.

Riscie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test and see. I still advocate starting small (*say 1 vCPU and 4GB RAM*) and adding resources as needed.

The problem is that many people configure their virtual machines to be [far larger than necessary](https://serverfault.com/questions/528254/vsphere-education-what-are-the-downsides-of-configuring-vms-with-too-much-ra). Don't fall into that trap.

There is no sweet spot, as it will depend on what you eventually run on the system. You have resources and tools within the VM to identify poor performance, so take advantage of virtualization's flexibility to adjust and right-size your VMs.

Comment: I agree that starting small and allocate more if necessary is the way to go and that it depends on what will be running on the vm. Still I am curious if there is theoreticaly a point, where the os is not benefiting anymore from more sockets and cores... Maybe someone can point me to tests which where already made, as I was not able to find any for Windows 2012 Server.

Comment: @Riscie Of course there is no such thing. Every server runs a different workload!

Comment: @Riscie When you're over the physical server's limits... or approaching them. E.g. don't spec an 8 vCPU VM on a host with 8 physical cores.